# How to save csv file to local path, not to download it?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with angular ts, and trying to save a csv file locally, not to download it, can anyone please help me, I don`t know how.
Firstly I save the content in a array, clean it and when I tried to save it locally,(the better will be in the aseets folder but I think its read only I'm right?). I got stocked.

Here is my code:

```
 exportToCsv(filename: string, rows: object[]) {
    if (!rows || !rows.length) {
      return;
    }
    const separator = ',';
    const keys = Object.keys(rows[0]);
    const csvContent =
      keys.join(separator) +
      '\n' +
      rows.map(row => {
        return keys.map(k => {
          let cell = row[k] === null || row[k] === undefined ? '' : row[k];
          cell = cell instanceof Date
            ? cell.toLocaleString()
            : cell.toString().replace(/"/g, '""');
          if (cell.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0) {
            cell = `"${cell}"`;
          }
          return cell;
        }).join(separator);
      }).join('\n');



// not working
     /*  //if (this.plt.is('cordova')) 
        this.file.writeFile('.\\src\\assets', filename, csvContent, {replace: true}) */

// download
   /*  const blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
      navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      if (link.download !== undefined) {
        // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.setAttribute('href', url);
        link.setAttribute('download', filename);
        link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
      } */

  }
```

Comment: you can't save file directly into local. It is not allowed as it causes security risks. go through this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914772/how-to-save-a-file-to-my-desktop-folder-angular-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a backend service to accomplish this. Angular builds javascript from the ts files. Javascript in the browser can not modify data on your computer directly because of security risks. Browser handle your frontend sites like boxes.

Comment: so what can be a way i'll be able to save data from my angular program and get it on Init, not using db?

Comment: Do you want to save it client side? If not, you just need to create a backend service for this (for example in NodeJS). Save the file on the server with ````writeFile````. So with a simple ````readFile```` function you can read it as well and send back to the client as a http response.

Comment: I'm a brand new developer, can you please explain me how to add node.js to my angular project in vsCode...

Comment: @אסתר Try to google `MEAN stack`. Do a simple init tutorial about it. I guess it is going to help you a lot.